# SQL Server Join two tables with where condition on both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have got two table clinical_study and location_countries, they both have NCT_ID (clinical trial) field in common, i have to pull data from both tables applying a condition on first table(Gender) and then also checking for country match in the second table,
i successfully managed to run the below query, but its under country field i am getting UK and other countries

```
select 
clinical_study.NCT_ID, clinical_study.BRIEF_SUMMARY, clinical_study.STUDY_TYPE, clinical_study.GENDER, location_countries.COUNTRY
from clinical_study

inner join location_countries
ON clinical_study.NCT_ID=location_countries.NCT_ID

where clinical_study.GENDER LIKE'Male' or clinical_study.GENDER like 'Both'

and  location_countries.COUNTRY ='United Kingdom'
```

NCT_ID.....BRIEF_SUMMARY.....STUDY_TYPE.....GENDER.....COUNTRY

xys........xyz...............xyz............Both.......United Kingdom

xys........xyz...............xyz............Male.......France

xys........xyz...............xyz............Male.......United Kingdom

xys........xyz...............xyz............Male.......Sweden

could you please advice if i am missing a trick here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to add some brackets

```
select 
    clinical_study.NCT_ID, clinical_study.BRIEF_SUMMARY, clinical_study.STUDY_TYPE, clinical_study.GENDER, location_countries.COUNTRY
from clinical_study
inner join location_countries
ON clinical_study.NCT_ID=location_countries.NCT_ID
where (clinical_study.GENDER LIKE'Male' or clinical_study.GENDER like 'Both')
and  location_countries.COUNTRY ='United Kingdom'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that AND has precedence over OR so it will be evaluated first. So you can use brackets to force precedence.

```
  where (clinical_study.GENDER LIKE'Male' or clinical_study.GENDER like 'Both')
  and  location_countries.COUNTRY ='United Kingdom'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets arround your OR clause

```
where (clinical_study.GENDER LIKE'Male' or clinical_study.GENDER like 'Both')
and  location_countries.COUNTRY ='United Kingdom'
```